# Where do I add a file do hold custom configuration variables for my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

Where do I add a file do hold custom configuration variables for my wordpress website ?

e.g.

```
$config['forbidden_users'] = array("admin", "host");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save it in functions.php. Or you can add this in wp-configs.php. But right solve is add it in funcitons.php. You have 2 ways. First you can create global variable. Second You can create function which will return array("admin","host");

Answer (score 1):

You could create a global in functions.php